# Javascript - how to select part of an image to change color

Tags: javascript, css, image

I have an image that is completely white. I want to select certain hexagonal sections to make them different colors, and then make the sections act like buttons that call different functions when they're clicked. I think I know how I would change the background color and make them clickable, but I don't know how to select a hexagonal section to change those things. Can anyone help me? (without jQuery)

**EDIT:** I figured out how to change set apart the hexagonal sections, and how to make them clickable like a button, but I can't figure out how to change the color of each part. How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an image map:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

[HTML < map> Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Here's a hexagon example:

[HTML Color Picker](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp)

Comment: how can I make a hexagon? Than example only has rectangles and circles.

Comment: well how would I MAKE it?

Comment: Do you know a way where you use the <map> and <area> tags to make them?

Comment: I figured out how to make a hexagon, but I don't know how to change the background color. Do you know how to?

Comment: You could create a css class and assign to each area element with the different background colours and then onclick change the class for that element, sorry but i don't have any example for this.